# Finite subgroup of $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a symmetric group

Tags: geometry, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I have the following exercise: Let $H$ be a finite subgroup of $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. the group of all isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that there exists a set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $H$ is the symmetry group of $X$.

I think that we can start with a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the orbit of this point under the action of $H$, however this orbit set might be too big. So I am thinking about adding more points to this orbit so that we can reduce its symmetry group, however it is not so clear...

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I thinkthat all appearences of the word "symmetric" in your posr should be instead of the word "symmetry".

Comment: You're right! Thanks!

Comment: @mapping, The case $n=2$ already illustrates all the features of the problem.  Two questions:

(1) Can a transformation $A \in H$ change the Euclidean norm of a vector $x \in X$?  (Hint: if $A \in H$, then so are $A^{k}$ for $k = 2, 3, \ldots$.

(2)  Can $A \in H$ be a rotation by an angle an irrational multiple of $2 \pi$?

Comment: @avs In the case $n=2$, everything is clear: First we can assume that $H$ is a finite subgroup of $O(2)$, and hence every element of $H$ preserves vector norms (this answers your first question). Second, if we consider $H^+$ the intersection of $H$ and $SO(2)$ then we can prove that $H^+$ is generated by a rotation of angle $2\pi/k$ (due to the finiteness of $H$), and so $H^+$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_k$. Then it follows that $H$ is either $\mathbb{Z}_k$ or $D_k$, the dihedral group of order $2k$. In both case it is easy to find $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ so that $H=Sym(X)$...

Comment: @avs (sorry since my previous comment is too long) ...It is not so clear how we can extend this method to general $n$: to know exactly the type of $H$ in general is difficult.

Comment: @mapping, a key piece of information is that every element of $H$ must have finite order in $Isom({\bf R}^{n})$.  (So, it cannot be, say, a rotation (about any axis) by an irrational multiple of $2 \pi$.  It can be a reflection through a hyperspace: these have order 2.)  Therefore, the orbit of an $x$ under the action of an $h \in H$ must also be finite and must lie on the unit sphere in ${\bf R}^{n}$.

Comment: @avs I agree, but the fact that the orbit of an x is finite can be seen easily since $H$ is finite, and it's clear that this orbit lies on a sphere because $H$ consists of only isometries... Nevertheless I do not see how it is useful to construct a subset $X$ as required.

Comment: @mapping, your last sentence questions the aim of the exercise, to which I cannot speak conclusively.:)  My guess: to make you look for some sort of an equivalence relation on ${\bf R}^{n}$ induced by an $h \in H$.  For instance, if $h$ is a reflection through a hyperplane, then this reflection permutes the two half-spaces.  Picking a point $x$ interior to one half-space, we get the finite set $\{x, hx\}$, on which $h$ acts like the symmetric group $S_{2}$.

Comment: BTW, I don't see why the orbit of a point $x$ would be "too big".  This orbit is a finite set, as we've seen, whose elements are permuted by $H$.